# English C++ program on foreign OS

Tags: c++, sockets, chat, translation

I have a chat system that works perfectly for Operating Systems in English. It uses the Multibyte character set, as does the server that drives it.

I have Chinese clients who use the program. When messages are received, one of two things happens: if the message was typed in Chinese, spaces aren't displayed. If it was written English, bits and pieces show up as foreign characters.

Any advice?

Comment: I imagine this has something to do with encoding and endianness. Is everything being sent in network byte order (big-endian) and/or properly converted to the byte order of the machine?

Comment: Give us more detail please. How your program communicate with OS, type of OS. it might be by chance different OD version not necessary the language since you say English are alright

Comment: Are you using UTF-8? UTF-16? UTF-32? Something else? Using a singular character encoding is ideal.

Comment: Aahh! I didn't even consider endian-ness. I know about it, I understand how it works, and I completely let it slip my mind. It's a Windows 7 PC through Windows Server 2008 R2 to another Windows 7 PC. How would I go about handling endian-ness in C++ sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Windows 7 for client and Windows Server 2008 R2 for server, I don't think that your issue is due to change of "endianness". You mentioned that you use "multibyte" character set. So I assume that your data does not use one of the standard Unicode encodings such as UTF-8/UTF-16/UTF-32 but rather uses the pre-Unicode style code pages for encoding the data. If one code page is used when a client enters a text into chat and is displayed with a different code page on recepient's PC, the text may not display properly.

Comment: Alright, I'll rebuild everything to use a unicode format when I can, it's quite a process. Do I have to convert internal strings as well, or only chat-based strings?